# .NET add custom properties to winform controls

Tags: winforms, properties, custom-controls

It would be useful to attach a bunch of custom properties to standard controls in .NET, **without creating a set of custom controls**.

I heard that its possible with WPF, but does somebody knows a solution for plain winform application?

Why? For example, when a control has the focus and its a TextBox, or a DropDownList or a ComboBox, then I want to paint its backcolor in the custom property I could name: "focusColor"

And of course, I do not want to create custom buttons, combos or dropdown...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In WPF it is done with [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx). Although there is no exact equivalent in Windows Form, you can implement an [`IExtenderProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider.aspx) to "attach" a custom property to a control. This property can then be used in the designer, like a normal property. See the code provided in [this blog post](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/05/06/windows-forms-automatically-drag-and-drop-controls-dragmove/) for an example.

Here's an implementation for your "FocusColor" example:

```
[ProvideProperty("FocusColor", typeof(Control))]
public class FocusColorProvider : Component, IExtenderProvider
{
    private readonly Dictionary<IntPtr, Color> _focusColors;
    private readonly Dictionary<IntPtr, Color> _backColors;

    public FocusColorProvider()
    {
        _focusColors = new Dictionary<IntPtr, Color>();
        _backColors = new Dictionary<IntPtr, Color>();
    }

    public bool CanExtend(object extendee)
    {
        return (extendee is Control);
    }

    public Color GetFocusColor(Control ctl)
    {
        Color color;
        if (_focusColors.TryGetValue(ctl.Handle, out color))
        {
            return color;
        }
        return ctl.BackColor;
    }

    public void SetFocusColor(Control ctl, Color color)
    {
        Color backColor;
        if (!_backColors.TryGetValue(ctl.Handle, out backColor))
        {
            backColor = ctl.BackColor;
        }

        // Same color as BackColor, disable the behavior
        if (color == backColor)
        {
            RemoveFocusColor(ctl);
            ctl.LostFocus -= ctl_LostFocus;
            ctl.GotFocus -= ctl_GotFocus;
            _focusColors.Remove(ctl.Handle);
        }
        else
        {
            _focusColors[ctl.Handle] = color;
            if (ctl.Focused)
                ApplyFocusColor(ctl);
            ctl.LostFocus += ctl_LostFocus;
            ctl.GotFocus += ctl_GotFocus;
        }
    }

    void ctl_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ApplyFocusColor((Control)sender);
    }

    void ctl_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveFocusColor((Control)sender);
    }

    void ApplyFocusColor(Control ctl)
    {
        _backColors[ctl.Handle] = ctl.BackColor;
        ctl.BackColor = GetFocusColor(ctl);
    }

    void RemoveFocusColor(Control ctl)
    {
        Color color;
        if (_backColors.TryGetValue(ctl.Handle, out color))
        {
            ctl.BackColor = color;
            _backColors.Remove(ctl.Handle);
        }
    }
}
```

Add this code to your project, compile, and add a `FocusColorProvider` on your form using the designer. A new `FocusColor` property should appear on the property grid when you select a control, just set it to the color you want. The control's BackColor will be changed to this color when it takes focus.

Comment: Wow! Très joli, merci Thomas :-)

Comment: Thomas, some more help is needed!... When I copy/paste your code in a new project, I must add "using System.ComponentModel;", and also I have 2 errors saying: "Type or Namespace for Control not found" and same for "Color". Undable to compile the class :-(

Comment: Oops, got it working, just needed to add using system.drawing and system.windows.forms

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize the `Tag` property of each control to store custom data associated with that control. Create a class `MyCustomAttributes` and assign objects of that type to `MyControl.Tag`. This won't work in the designer, of course, only at run time.

As an alternative, you could derive some classes like `ExtTextBox` from `TextBox`, `ExtDropDownList` from `DropDrownList` etc., having some additional attributes. That is a very simple and painless way of creating custom controls, which might be acceptable in your case, even if you said you don't want such a solution.